# CQL INSERT fails with "SyntaxException: line 1:32 no viable alternative at input '1'"

Tags: cassandra, nosql

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE test.messages_by_channel (
    channel_id int,
    message_id timeuuid,
    message text,
    user_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (channel_id, message_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'ALL'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

When I run this:

```
insert into messages_by_channel(1, now(), "test", 2);
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxException: line 1:32 no viable alternative at input '1'
```

How can I run this insert query and generate unique timeuuid ?

Answer (score 1):

As the error `SyntaxException` indicates, your `INSERT` failed because the syntax is incorrect.

You need to enumerate the columns you wish to update in your CQL statement. The simplified syntax format is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
    VALUES (values_to_insert)
```

In your case the correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO messages_by_channel (channel_id, message_id, message, user_id)
    VALUES (1, NOW(), 'test', 2)
```

Note that the message text is enclosed in single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`).

You need to enumerate the columns being inserted because Cassandra has sparse storage -- columns which are not assigned a value are not stored on disk. For details, see [CQL Data Manipulation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/dml.html).

If you're interested, we have free interactive tutorials at [datastax.com/dev](https://www.datastax.com/dev). If you're new to Cassandra, I highly recommend doing the [Cassandra Fundamentals](https://www.datastax.com/learn/cassandra-fundamentals) course where you can learn the basics and core concepts very quickly. Cheers!